# Delphi Android app gives me a copy of the image from the gallery. How do I get the original?

Tags: android, delphi, gallery, delphi-10.3-rio

Trying to get an image from Gallery - it works fine, but I get the recompressed copy instead.

I'm using following simple code to get the image from the gallery on Android:

```
procedure TakePhotoFromGallery;
begin
  FParams.RequiredResolution := TSize.Create(MaxInt, MaxInt);
  // FParams.RequiredResolution := TSize.Create(3000, 4000); specifiying original dimensions does not help
  FParams.Editable := False; // Don't ask user to edit the photo after selecting it
  FParams.NeedSaveToAlbum := False; // Seems to have no effect

  if TPlatformServices.Current.SupportsPlatformService(IFMXTakenImageService, FGalleryService) then
    FGalleryService.TakeImageFromLibrary(nil, FParams);
end;
```

I'm subscribed to `TMessageReceivedImagePath` and receive the image like so:

```
procedure TMyObject.ReceivedImagePath(const Sender: TObject; const M: TMessage);
begin
  if M is TMessageReceivedImagePath then
    Log.d('ReceivedImagePath ' + TMessageReceivedImagePath(M).Value);
end;
```

It all works fine, but there's one problem. For some reason I get **the copy** of the image from the gallery with EXIF missing. Original image is 3000x400px 2.5mb, and I get the 3000x4000px 3.45mb. I need the original to read its EXIF data.

How do I get the original image?

Comment: Same question in Russian: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/952957

Comment: You cannot with IFMXTakenImageService, because it converts the image to a bitmap, thus loses the EXIF information. You either need to use the native camera APIs, or use startActivityForResult using an Intent with an action of ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE from the MediaStore class. I have a demo of how to do the latter here, however it needs to be updated to support API 26+: https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/KastriFree/tree/master/Demos/ObtainPhotoInfoDemo

Comment: @DaveNottage I have seen this code, but could not adapt it to 10.3 (still new to Android stuff). However, taking photo from camera retains EXIF. It's only the taking photo from gallery that "kills" it (at least in my case).

Comment: I've now updated the code to cater for Rio. The trick is for me is that my camera now appears to not include EXIF information in the picture. Might be different for others.